# как правильно загрузить фото в background LinearLayout с помощью Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

пробую поставить в фон картинку используя UML, но возникла проблема.

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("", imageAware);
```

displayImage требует на вход строку, вторым параметром я обернул
вот так

```
ImageAware imageAware  = new BgViewAware(mLinearLayout);
а вот с первым не знаю как сделать. картинка лежат в drawable.
достаю так
        Drawable drawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test_fon);
```

а как положить картинку не знаю.
в BgViewAware есть метод

```
 @Override
    protected void setImageDrawableInto(Drawable drawable, View view) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

но как сюда правильно подать картинку?
пробовал так:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("", imageAware.setImageDrawableInto(drawable,mLinearLayout));
```

но тоже не верно.. как быть? подскажите?
UDATE: пробовал так :

```
String imageUri1 = "drawable://" + getActivity().getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.test_fon); ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri1, imageAware);
```

но тоже почему-то не идет...

Comment: UDATE:
пробовал так :
 String imageUri1 = "drawable://" + getActivity().getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.test_fon);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri1, imageAware);
 но тоже почему-то не идет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужен UIL для этого. Просто установите вашему `LinearLayout` фон стандартным методом:

```
mLinearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test_fon);
```

Либо как-то так средствами UIL:

```
imageAware.setImageDrawableInto(drawable,mLinearLayout)
```

Comment: мне он нужен, так как  фото  хорошего качества, и при старте съедает 15 мб памяти, а вот как сделать так не получается

Comment: @Сергей, если вы используете для этого UIL, то он обрежет вашу картинку. Так почему бы вам самому это не сделать? В ручную? А так - см. обновление ответа

Comment: так вашим способом я пробовал, выше мой код есть, но не работает.
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("", imageAware.setImageDrawableInto(drawable,mLinearLayout));

Comment: если сам обрежу, то как мне потом осуществить масштабирование под большие экраны? разве  UML не  не сохраняет в кэше полноразмерную картинку?

Comment: Вы лишний код вокруг строки подставили. А в кэш может попасть обрезанная версия. Там вообще всё сложно(

Comment: И скорее всего, т.к. как вы сами писали в итоге будет вызван стандартный метод ничего нигде не обрежется.

Comment: вы оказались правы, все-таки сделал чтоб работало, но по памяти вышло ровно столько же...видимо как вы и сказали вызвался стандартный метод..

Comment: если руками подрезать, то надо получать программно размеры экрана и подгонять?

Comment: а если у меня много активити будет, то  так ведь много памяти уйдет.. можно ли как то сделать так что если ушел с одного фрагмента на другой, то старую картинку убрать из памяти? просто она у меня хранится как бы получается.. кэшировать ее что ли? или просто удалять?

Comment: @Сергей, вы можете руками нарезать n изображений и раскидать их по разным папкам в проекте. Типа drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi etc. Так разные девайсы будут из разных папок брать картинки разных размеров.

Comment: Вы можете в методах жизненного цикла при желании обнулять/очищать фон разметки и восстанавливать его там же (в onResume(), например). Так памяти много, наверное, не будет есть.

Comment: я пробовал так обнулять. linear.setBackround(null) но ему на вход нужен int..

Comment: @Сергей, пишите так: `setBackgroundDrawable(null);`

Comment: спасибо, помогло